# How to find an object by id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have this collection of objects:

```
const objects = [
  { id: '11', name: 'ron', surname: 'lesner', group: 'A' },
  { id: '12', name: 'don', surname: 'lesner', group: 'B' },
  { id: '13', name: 'ton', surname: 'lesner', group: 'A' },
]
```

I need to return the object with matching id using Lodash.

The following code returns `undefined`:

```
_.find(object, id, 11);
```

I'm expecting this result:

```
{ id: '11', name: 'ron' , surname: 'lesner' , group: 'A' }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `'11'` - string representation of the `11` number, because your id is of type `string`. With [**Lodash#find**](https://lodash.com/docs/#find)

```js
const object = [
     {id: '11', name: 'ron' , surname: 'lesner' , group: 'A'},
     {id: '12', name: 'don' , surname: 'lesner' , group: 'B'},
     {id: '13', name: 'ton' , surname: 'lesner' , group: 'A'}
];

const found = _.find(object , ['id', '13']);

console.log(found);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Also you can use pure Javascript instead of lodash?

```js
const object = [
     {id: '11', name: 'ron' , surname: 'lesner' , group: 'A'},
     {id: '12', name: 'don' , surname: 'lesner' , group: 'B'},
     {id: '13', name: 'ton' , surname: 'lesner' , group: 'A'}
];

const found = object.find(item => item.id === '11');

console.log(found);
```

Comment: actually I am coding in Typescript so wondering if any new design pattern will be seen.it is okay with javascript also.

Comment: Is this a lodash? ._find is not used.

Comment: I need to use lodash function only

Comment: @Aditya See updated. I have provided lodash version

Comment: okay..will try and update.

Comment: found = undefined I am getting

Comment: See my examples

Comment: I tried const `found = _.find(object , 'id', '13');` it returns me the first object always..and not actual 13th one

Comment: and using with`found = _.find(object , ['id', '13']);` return as undefined

Comment: Work with my examples. Something wrong is in your local

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the lodash find function in accordance with hiw its intended to be used. Please check source code and coments at https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/find.js

Also for something so trivial it can be argued that you should better use the native array functions if you cannot motivate library use with the need for extreeme performance or other reasons; and also dont call an array Object. It will make your code confusing.